# Catch highlights and URLs in new windows

Tags: irc, irssi

In irssi, I want all highlights and all URLs to be catched into two separate windows.
I.e., when another user highlights me, that message will also appear in a new/other window together with a notification about which channel this message was sent in.

Are there any irssi scripts or anything that will fix this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about URLs, but the script `hilightwin.pl` does exactly as you describe for highlights and private messages. Any messages containing highlights or private messages sent to you are duplicated into a window named "hilight". Simply show and sticky this window to make it always visible:
`/window new`
`/window name hilight`
`/window goto 1`
`/window show hilight`
`/window stick on`